# In my asteroid game, I can't move my ship on the x coordinates

Tags: c++, c++17

Just draw a ship for an Asteroid game but can't move it in x coordinates, it moves on the y coordinates and also rotating correctly but the variables dx can't get bigger values?

I used some French names for variables just ignore them. I'm a beginner struggling with classes.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

const int L = 800;
const int H = 500;
double deg_rad = 0.017444;

void astroid(double &xa, double &ya){

double dxa = 1;
xa -= dxa;
if(xa > L) xa = 0; if(xa < 0) xa = L;
}

void joueur (bool thrust, double &x, double &y, double &angle){
int Vmax = 2;
double vitesse;
double dx, dy;
if(thrust){
        dx += cos(angle*deg_rad)*0.2;
        dy += sin(angle*deg_rad)*0.2;}
else{
        dx *= 1;
        dy *= 1;}
    cout << dx << " " <<dy << " " <<angle<<endl;

    vitesse = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    if(vitesse > Vmax){
        dx *= Vmax/vitesse;
        dy *= Vmax/vitesse;}

    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    if(x > L) x = 0; if(x < 0) x = L;
    if(y > H) y = 0; if(y < 0) y = H;
 }

int main(void)
{
double xa, ya ;
double y = 400, x = 200;
double angle = 0;
bool thrust;
srand(time(NULL));

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(L,H), "Sauver notre Planet");
window.setFramerateLimit(60);

Texture tex1,tex2,tex3;
tex1.loadFromFile("images/ship.png");
tex2.loadFromFile("images/background1.jpg");
tex3.loadFromFile("images/asteroid1.png");

tex1.setSmooth(true);
tex2.setSmooth(true);

Sprite sJoueur(tex1), sBackground(tex2), sAsteroid(tex3);

sJoueur.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 80, 80));
sJoueur.setScale(0.8,0.8);
sJoueur.setOrigin(40,40);

sAsteroid.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 80, 80));
sAsteroid.setScale(0.8,0.8);
sAsteroid.setOrigin(40,40);

xa = 900;
ya = rand()%H;

while(window.isOpen()){
    Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
        if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
          if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Space)
             window.close();

    //Controle Clavier
   if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) angle += 3;
   if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) angle -= 3;
   if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) thrust = true;
   else thrust = false;

   joueur(thrust, x, y, angle);
   astroid(xa, ya);

   sJoueur.setPosition(x,y);
   sJoueur.setRotation(angle+90);

   sAsteroid.setPosition(xa, ya);

    //Dessin
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sBackground);
    window.draw(sJoueur);
    window.draw(sAsteroid);
    window.display();
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please always add a **minimal reproducible code example** to your question (not your full code) to make it easier for us to reproduce the problem and find an answer. This also avoid frustrating downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem (It's hard to tell without having the program in a debugger to see some of the values), but I noticed that you are adding and multiplying `dx`, `dy` in `joueur` before initializing them. This doesn't make sense and could be causing undefined behavior.